# JavaFX Styling a Graphic-Node of a Button via CSS

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, styling

I'm trying to recreate the LookAndFeel I used in Swing.

Everything works so far, but I fail by styling the Graphic-Node of a Button.

Java-Code:

```
Button btnAdd= new Button();
btnAdd.setGraphic(iconAdd); //iconAdd = ImageView
```

CSS:

```
.button:disabled, .button:default:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
    -fx-background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    -fx-border-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
}

.button:disabled > .graphic  {
    -fx-opacity: 0.1;
}
```

As you can see, I want the Button to be non-transparent whenever it is disabled (this works!).

I only want the Graphic-Node, which is a child of the Button, to be transparent.

Best regards,

strongp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphic in a button does not automatically get the style class `graphic`, so you need to add it:

```
iconAdd.getStyleClass().add("graphic");
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonGraphicCssTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button();
        Image image = new Rectangle(20, 20, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE).snapshot(null, null);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.getStyleClass().add("graphic");
        button.setGraphic(imageView);

        button.setOnAction(e -> button.setDisable(true));

        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("button-graphic-disabled.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

button-graphic-disabled.css:

```
.button:disabled, .button:default:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
    -fx-background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    -fx-border-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
}

.button:disabled > .graphic  {
    -fx-opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP can also use the default `.image-view` class. `.button:disabled > .image-view { -fx-opacity: 0.1; }` should also do the job.